# Can't play DVDs through either VLC, Videos, or Kaffeine

Tags: video, vlc, dvd

Running this through an external DVD drive. Videos app says `DVD source is required to play the file, but is not installed.` Hitting play in VLC activates the disc (you can hear it start up in the drive) but nothing happens. I've installed Ubuntu Restricted Extras and libdvdread4 and libdvdcss.

I know varieties of this question have been asked before, but none of the answers I've tracked down are solving the issue.

Comment: I hope you have the drivers installed properly

Comment: Well, gee, I do too, but do you have any actual suggestions?

Comment: Have you installed `libdvdnav4` as well?  Also, what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Yes, `libdvdnav4` did it. Thanks!

Comment: I'll write that up as a quick answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When it comes to playing DVDs in Ubuntu, the `libdvd` applications needed to play DVDs are not installed by default.  To install them run the following:

From a terminal window:

First, enable the Universe/Multiverse repositories:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt update
```

Then install the missing applications:

```
sudo apt install libdvdcss2 libdvdread4 libdvdnav4 ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

You may have to install the libdvd-pkg instead:

```
sudo apt install libdvd-pkg
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: ubuntu-restricted-extras was necessary in my case

Comment: This did not permit me to watch a DVD on VLC 3.0.4 in Ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: @Lexible I believe that for 18.10 it is just the package of `libdvd-pkg` to be installed for DVDs.

Comment: @Terrance Nope.

Comment: @Lexible Hmm, don't know what else to tell you.  I just did a clean install of 18.10 here and installed the `libdvd-pkg` and everything worked fine.  I was able to play DVDs in VLC 3.0.4.