# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS won't play a commercial DVD

Tags: dvd

The following output appears when I attempt to run a commercial DVD in totem. Can anyone explain what the output is telling me?

```
cale@fit-PC4:~$ totem
cale@fit-PC4:~$ totem

(totem:3529): GLib-CRITICAL **: 12:14:15.789: g_key_file_load_from_file: assertion 'file != NULL' failed
libdvdread: Attempting to use device /dev/sr0 mounted on /media/cale/DDPY REBUILD - DISC 1 for CSS authentication
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 6.0.0
libdvdread: Attempting to use device /dev/sr0 mounted on /media/cale/DDPY REBUILD - DISC 1 for CSS authentication
libdvdnav: Can't read name block. Probably not a DVD-ROM device.
libdvdnav: vm: dvd_read_name failed
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00000000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

libdvdread: Attempting to retrieve all CSS keys
libdvdread: This can take a _long_ time, please be patient

libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.VOB at 0x000632a4
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_0.VOB at 0x000632d8
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_1.VOB at 0x00063c00
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_02_0.VOB at 0x000670f6
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_02_1.VOB at 0x0006f189
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_03_0.VOB at 0x00072fcf
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_03_1.VOB at 0x00072fd3
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_04_0.VOB at 0x00076046
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_04_1.VOB at 0x0007604a
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_05_0.VOB at 0x000791a3
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_05_1.VOB at 0x000791a7
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_06_0.VOB at 0x0007da16
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_06_1.VOB at 0x0007da1a
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_07_0.VOB at 0x00081957
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_07_1.VOB at 0x0008195b
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_08_0.VOB at 0x00084555
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_08_1.VOB at 0x00084559
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_09_0.VOB at 0x0017c671
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_09_1.VOB at 0x0017c675
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_10_0.VOB at 0x0017d0ab
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_10_1.VOB at 0x0017d0af
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_11_0.VOB at 0x001c417a
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_11_1.VOB at 0x001c417e
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_12_0.VOB at 0x00209a8a
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_12_1.VOB at 0x00209a8e
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_13_0.VOB at 0x0025fcf8
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_13_1.VOB at 0x0025fcfc
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_14_0.VOB at 0x002ad865
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_14_1.VOB at 0x002ad869
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_15_0.VOB at 0x003154c2
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_15_1.VOB at 0x003154c6
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Found 15 VTS's
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
mesa: for the -simplifycfg-sink-common option: may only occur zero or one times!

(totem:3529): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:14:22.765: Drawing a gadget with negative dimensions. Did you forget to allocate a size? (node slider owner GtkScale)
Killed
```

Comment: Maybe this might help:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1013303/231142